# Do I have to implement garbage collection manually in Java?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm, command-line-arguments

I already read some about garbage collection in Java, but I can't find the "best practice" to handle the garbage collection in code. Should I set every variable to `null` after use, or is it more efficient and performant to just use the default garbage collector? Or do I have to configure the garbage collector through the command line arguments in this case?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: No, you have not

Comment: You are not supposed to handle any of that yourself. Java does all of that behind the scenes.
You can add calls to the GC in your code specifically, but they'll just be "requests" to run the GC, they don't guarantee that it'll actually run.
What you can do, is make sure that when variables become obsolete, you flag them as ready to be garbage collected

Comment: Best practice is to let the JVM deal with it.  Leave it alone.  Mostly.   Assigning `null` to variables is nearly always unnecessary.  Running the GC is nearly always inadvisable; i.e. a bad idea.  Tuning the GC is only advisable if you have clear evidence that the GC is behaving badly.  (Ill-advised GC tuning may make GC performance worse than leaving it alone.)

Comment: As with all optimizations: Forget it. Avoid stupid algorithms (e.g., bubble sort), use good data structures (there are tons of them in Java itself, more in Guava and other libraries), write clean code with short methods. Especially the GC is meant  to work as is, the best practice for 99% cases is leaving it alone as more experienced people have tuned it already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, JVM does it for you. That's why it's a language with automatic memory management. If you want, because of performance issues, you can call:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
r.gc();
```

but there is no guarantee, that garbage collector will remove non-referenced objects. It's rather a suggestion for JVM. **Only if you know what you're doing. At your own risk.**

What you can do is choose an implementation of garbage collector, that suits your needs. For example if you don't want to reclaim any memory, for testing purposes, you can choose [epsilon](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/318) by adding `XX:+UseEpsilonGC` flag.

Comment: Bad advice.  Running the `gc()` by hand is liable to make application performance worse ... 'cos an application doesn't usually have enough info to know when is the right time to run it.

Answer (score 2):

The Garbage Collector mostly do the work himself. You dont need to anything. But you can even watch the Garbage Collector clearing the JVM Memory as seen in the picture

[image: its not hard to tell where the garbage collector did his job... From https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dsyer/spring-boot-memory-blog/master/manual-gc-web.png]

> Automatic garbage collection is the process of looking at heap memory, identifying which objects are in use and which are not, and deleting the unused objects.

further information:[Java Garbage Collection Basics](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)